# *** RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors does not require grad

Tags: pytorch

```
        GN_params = list(np.load('/home/linghuxiongkun/workspace/guided-diffusion/guided_diffusion/GN_param_names.npy'))
        for k,v in self.model.named_parameters():
            if k not in GN_params:
                v.requires_grad = False
        self.opt = AdamW(
        filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.model.parameters()), lr=self.lr, weight_decay=self.weight_decay
```

I try to fine tune part of the parameters of the network, but the error occurs. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Eric to the community. Although we might benefit from more information on your side in order to reproduce the bug. However it seems the error message is straightforward.

It looks like you are trying to fine tune on a some tensors that do not require gradients. Normally you would fine tune only on the network heads leaving the backbone frozen. In here it seems that the optimizer is trying to run gradient over the frozen part of the network.

Instead of filtering the model parameters by `requires_grad` try just passing the parameters.

```py
# Change the optimizer call
self.opt = AdamW(
    self.model.parameters(), lr=self.lr, weight_decay=self.weight_decay
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I use your code, however, the same error occurs.

Comment: Then it seems that a GN param name from GN_param_names is being set to trainable false or require_grad false when it is not supposed to, why don't you add more code / context so I can be of more help?

Comment: I filter all the GroupNormalization parameters to only fine tune GroupNormalization parameters. Then this error occurs, however, when I filter other parameters such as Res block, the training process can work normally.